# vertical scrolling on hover instead of click? jquery api

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I am using jQuery scrollTo to scroll contents within a div that is overflown.  When I click the links, the div will vertically scroll its contents. However, I would like this effect to occur when I hover over the links, instead of click them.

I don't believe this is an option with jQuery's scrollTo.  However, there is a jQuery API method for `hover` event.

This may seem like a simply question, but is there a way to maintain my vertical scrolling functionality of "scrollTo" by hovering over instead of clicking?

Vertical scroll:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'y';
    $.localScroll({
        target: '#content',
        // could be a selector or a jQuery object too.
        queue: true,
        duration: 500,
        hash: false,
        onBefore: function (e, anchor, $target) {
            // The 'this' is the settings object, can be modified
        },
        onAfter: function (anchor, settings) {
            // The 'this' contains the scrolled element (#content)
        }
    });
});
```

Hovering:

```
$("#page-wrap li.button").hover(function(){ /* vertically slide here? */ });V
```

Answer (score 1):

Smooth scrolling with scrollTo plugin:

```
        $('#page-wrap li.button-down').hover(function(){
            var scrollDistance = $('body').scrollTop();
            var scrollHeight = $('#content').height();
            var windowHeight = $('body').height();
            var scrollSpeed = (scrollHeight - scrollDistance - windowHeight) * 2.5;  // higher than 2.5 is slower, lower is faster
            $('body').scrollTo('100%', scrollSpeed);
        },function(){
            $('body').stop().scrollTo('+=20px', 100);
            // stop on unhover
        });
```

This will scroll down. It's simpler to make the scroll up button

```
        $('#page-wrap li.button-up').hover(function(){
            var scrollDistance = $('body').scrollTop();
            var scrollSpeed = scrollDistance * 2.5;  // higher than 2.5 is slower, lower is faster
            $('body').scrollTo('0px', scrollSpeed);
        },function(){
            $('body').stop().scrollTo('-=20px', 100);
            // stop on unhover
        });
```

fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Nkpr/1/